# Different rendering between .Rmd and .Rmarkdown when using blogdown

Tags: rstudio, blogdown

I have found some strange differences in the way .Rmd files are rendered compared to .Rmarkdown. 
My setup: 
Beautiful hugo theme
Blogdown 0.9
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
If change the file extension between Rmd and Rmarkdown, I observe the following differences:

1. Rmd doesn't render multi level lists properly
2. Rmd doesn't render footnotes [^1] properly
3. Rmarkdown doesn't render math properly
4. Python code chunks don't have a nice little execute button in the upper right in Rmd.

Is this expected behavior? Is there something with the theme that causes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the difference between `.Rmd` and `.Rmarkdown` is expected and [Yihui et al. outlines it in their book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html) (it's around the middle of the page)

- You cannot use Markdown features only supported by Pandoc, such as fenced `Div`s.
- Math expressions only work if you apply the JavaScript solution mentioned in Section [B.3](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/javascript.html).

The main thing to note is that `.Rmarkdown` gets converted to `.markdown` documents first and gets passed onto Hugo's Markdown renderer (e.g., `Goldmark` or `Blackfriday`) to generate a html while `.Rmd` uses `Pandoc` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. I read the whole book and tried to look back at it but I missed this.

Comment: More niche probably but also found `knitr::current_input()` behaves differently when in YAML header, as described here: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/647#issuecomment-1042757202

Comment: Per discussion on issue mentioned above, the most recent version of blogdown makes knitting behavior in the YAML header more consistent.